# Creating a new data frame with calculations in each column made with other data frames

Tags: r

Lets say I have data frame A. Data frame A has many columns and many rows.
I also have a data frame B. It only has one column with the same amount of rows.
I want to make a new data frame C. This data frame C would have same names for columns as data frame A. C should only have one row containing the calculations:

```
sum(A$column*B$column) + 0.6
```

To clarify, I should do the same calculations with each column of A but same column in B and put it into a new data frame as a new column containing with the same name containing the result:

```
c$column1 would contain sum(A$column1*B$column) + 0.6
c$column2 would contain sum(A$column2*B$column) + 0.6
c$column3 would contain sum(A$column3*B$column) + 0.6
```

and so on.

If it was just a few columns, I'd just do it by hand, but since there's 353 of them... I want to automate this, maybe with a for loop, but no idea how to do so. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do this. First make some toy data:

```
a <- data.frame(column1 = runif(5), column2 = runif(5), column3=runif(5))
b <- data.frame(column = 1:5)

> a
    column1   column2   column3
1 0.1848823 0.9434750 0.5526741
2 0.7023740 0.1291590 0.2388948
3 0.5733263 0.8334488 0.7605133
4 0.1680519 0.4680185 0.1808201
5 0.9438393 0.5499837 0.4052822
> b
  column
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
```

You could convert `a` to a matrix, multiply it element-wise by `b`, do your addition then convert back to a data frame:

```
> data.frame(as.matrix(a) * b$column + 0.6)
    column1  column2  column3
1 0.7848823 1.543475 1.152674
2 2.0047481 0.858318 1.077790
3 2.3199790 3.100346 2.881540
4 1.2722077 2.472074 1.323280
5 5.3191967 3.349919 2.626411
```

Or you could use `lapply` to multiply each column in turn by b, then turn the resulting list back into a data frame:

```
 data.frame(lapply(a , \(x) x*b$column+0.6))
    column1  column2  column3
1 0.7848823 1.543475 1.152674
2 2.0047481 0.858318 1.077790
3 2.3199790 3.100346 2.881540
4 1.2722077 2.472074 1.323280
5 5.3191967 3.349919 2.626411
```

Comment: Yes, this is getting me almost where I need to be. But my end goal would be to take all the multiplied rows, lets say in column1, sum them together, and only then create the new C data frame containing all the column names but the singular row containing the final sums. I'm sorry for not making this clear enough

Comment: so you want a data frame with only one row?

Comment: You could use matrix multiplication then: 
`as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(b)) %*% as.matrix(a) + 0.6)`

Or add the sum to the lapply: `data.frame(lapply(a , \(x) sum(x*b$column)+0.6))`

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Wasn't familiar with %*% so was thinking in the scope of more traditional programming

Answer (score 0):

A data frame is a list of vectors, one vector for each column.

So you can do:

```
C <- as.data.frame(lapply(A, \(col) col * B$column + 0.6))
```

Or, use tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
C <- A %>% mutate(across(.fns = \(col) col * B$column + 0.6))
```